# indid column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the main purpose of indid column in sysindexes table.
How is it given a value? On what basis?

Comment: Please tell which database you are using. You can add tags like sql-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indid identifies an index for a given table. You asked for the main purpose. Actually some numbers have special meaning. From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190283%28SQL.100%29.aspx):

> ID of the index: 0 = Heap; 1 =
>   Clustered index;
>   >1 = Nonclustered index